# Flexslider loads after images, and causes smoothHeight property to animate the image again

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate, flexslider

Two questions actually, both related to flexslider and may even be related to eachother.

1. I am using Flexslider ([http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/](http://grrr.dontmeshwithus.com/)) in my site http://grrr.dontmeshwithus.com/. I have Flexslider property smoothHeight set to true, so it allows the height of the slider to animate smoothly in horizontal mode. I have problem where when I reload the page, it loads the first image first and THEN it animates from 0 to image height. You can see how this is annoying and not wanted. Any ideas how to prevent this so that a) it doesn't animate the first image or b) it loads flexslider before the first image has loaded?
2. If you go to single post (eg. http://grrr.dontmeshwithus.com/ismo-alanko/ssdfs/) it shows current slide number and total slide number (eg. 3/5). But when I come to the page for the first time, or refresh the page, it resets the slider and doesn't show the current slide number. It's just empty. How can I make it show correctly it's current slide number (1). It shows the slide number for the first slide if I first go to slide two and then go back to slide one.

Here's my flexslider JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    keyboard: true,
    initDelay: 1000,
    useCSS: false,
    video: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: false,
    smoothHeight: true,
    controlsContainer: ".flexslider-control",
    nextText: ">",
    prevText: "<",
    after: function(slider) {
        $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide+1);
    },
    start: function(slider) {
        $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
    }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay these were actually really simple, that I should have thought more of before asking here.

1. I just moved the scripts to head, so they load first. duh.
2. Instead of

   ```
   after: function(slider) {
       $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide+1);
   },
   start: function(slider) {
       $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
   }
   ```

I did

```
after: function(slider) {
    $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide+1);
},
start: function(slider) {
    $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide+1);
    $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
}
```